# How to run both front end and backend on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Ok so my backend server is running on port  5050 and my front end is running on port 3000 but when I am trying to fetch the data from backend it is giving me a manifest.json not found error I have added proxy in package.json but still its not working any help would be appreciated here is some code from the fetch Function and routes

```
index.js in React

const Book =()=>{
const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

const getBooks = async ()=>{
  const response = await fetch("/books");
  
  const books = await response.json();  
  setBooks(books);
}



back End Logic

const getBooks = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        //getting list of all books in Book database
        const books = await Book.find();
         res.status(200).json(books);
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error.message)
        
    }

}
```

Comment: `const response = await fetch("/books");` this line tries to get data from http://localhost:3000/books.
Change it to:
 `const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5050/books");`

Comment: Does `books` need to be stringified?

Comment: when I set fetch("/localhost:3000/books) it gives me cors error

Comment: Even though I added proxy still not working throwing a different error manifest.sjon not found

here is proxy setup:|
"proxy": "http://localhost:5050"

Comment: The missing manifest error is probably unrelated. Check the XHR in the browser dev tools' console tab. Try `"proxy": "http://localhost:5050"`

Comment: I can't run the dev server when I try "proxy": "localhost": `When "proxy" is specified in package.json it must start with either http:// or https://` Please make sure what you put in your question or comments is **exactly** what you're using. Every letter is important.

Comment: Tried everything as you guys said still no luck :(